# Can I call a Springboot backend API from NextJS frontend through NextJS backend API?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, next.js, backend

Suppose I have a Backend RESTFul APIs created with Springboot and I'm creating its front-end with NextJS. NextJS also has a server side API gateway that we can call for back-end APIs as well. I know that we can call directly from the front-end NEXT component using fetch or axios to the springboot server, but Can we call NEXTJS API through front-end which will call springboot server api?
NextJS frontend --> NextJS apis --> Springboot apis

I'm expecting the response returned from Springboot APIs to the NextJS APIs, then I will include the response data to nextJS response object then returned to the front-end through nextJS response.

Comment: I don't see any reason for which you cannot.